# Grafana Alert Rules are not importing while dashboard import

Tags: database, grafana, alert, dashboard

I run grafana on 2 different servers. When I import the "Alerts - Windows Nodes" dashboard to grafana on my server 1, alert rules are added, but when I add "Alerts - Windows Nodes" dashboard to grafana on my server number 2, rules are not added to the alert rules.

Do you have any idea how can i solve it?

Thank you!

I tried to export "Alerts - Windows Nodes" dashboard to my Grafana v9.4.7 (my servers are in same version)
but ı can't see my rules in Grafana - Alert rules section.